# Check chained association existence in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a rails Model association setup where every `User` has_one `Buyer` and specific `Users` can register as a `Seller` as well (`has_one` association).

Also some of the buyers can be specified as `Elite` as another `has_one` relation to a `Buyer`.

Now I have a situation where I want to setup a `cron` job to check the activity of different `buyers` and exclude all `sellers` and `elite buyers`.

My method for the same is:

```
def self.create_daily_user_notifications
  @users = User.where({ banned: false, admin: false })
  @users = @users.reject {|u| u.seller or u.buyer.elite }
end
```

The problem in this situation is that if there is a condition where a `buyer` doesn't have an associated `elite` relation it actually gives an error `undefined method elite for buyer`.

I would guess it's because the join doesn't exist for situations where a `buyer` is not `elite`. Is there a way I can just add this check?

Comment: You mean you want to proceed with `u.buyer.elite` check and not to get the error?

Comment: @Pavan yes I want to be able to remove all users who are elite buyers without getting errors for those who are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then you can use [*`try`*](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) to silence the error and proceed with the check.

```
@users = @users.reject {|u| u.seller or u.buyer.try(:elite) }
```